# Using reserved words as table names in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a migration script (which was created using a tool) for migrating from MySQL to Oracle 11g. The table names we have are like USER, AUDIT, RESOURCE etc which are reserved words in Oracle so, when I ran the script It created these Tables with underscore at the ned of the name (USER_, AUDIT_ , etc. ). 
Now I found out that if I enclose the table names in quotes then we can use these words as is.

What is the way to handle foreign key constraint definition, do we apply quotes around table name there too?  Like references "RESOURCE"(ID).

Also how to not have _  As the appender (can we set this somewhere in the options before running the script. I am using Oracle SQL Developer)

Comment: Your last sentence should be a separate question.

Comment: I would recommend not using reserved words if at all possible. It will needlessly complicate and confuse things. If you're worried about changing things don't forget you'll have to change all code anyway to include quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the way to handle foreign key constraint definition, do we apply quotes around table name there too? Like references "RESOURCE"(ID).

Yes, all references to the table must be done via double quotes.